# Common database scripts for all RDBMS

Tags: sql, sql-scripts

I am developing a tool that will run database scripts to create tables in different RDBMS' through simple JDBC connection.

Now my problem is for JDBC connection creation for different RDBMS I have to write different SQL scripts, scripts for Sybase will not be the same as for Oracle or MySQL. It's becoming very tedious to write different scripts for different RDBMS.

So is there any common way to do this??

Answer (score 0):

If you do it by sql scripts then I am afraid there is no way.
The common aproach is to use a common programing language  (C#,java,...) and write everything trough there and just create conversion algoritms for different databases but you could also try NHibranate for instance in C# that can handle most common databases and allready has some methods for that also look at PetaPoco or Massive.

There are alot of aproaches to this but none of them is plug and play with each you would need some work but I don't know your workneeds